# how to apply different validation rules based upon path-variable in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

How do we implements custom validation rules based upon different path-variable iin spring-boot app?
In my case I have to apply some validation rules which are common and sone of them has different defineition based upon path-variable.

In below sample code, Controller will received request for url "/api/v1/validate/{processor}/". I have to apply validation based upon different processor name. It is obviious that few of validations are common but some validations for the same field has different rules based upon processor passed.

Suppose permiitted values for processor are: retailer and merchant.

Common Rules:

1. id, firstName, lastName cannot be null and blank
2. id must be integer greate than 0 and of smaller than 10000.
3. firstName and lastName does not contain number and special character.

Rules specific to retailer:

1. first name and last name should have length less than 50
2. first name can contain space.
3. address cannot be longer than 100

Rules specific to merchant:

1. first name and last name should have length less than 100
2. first name and last name should not have space.
3. address must be smaller than 150

My question is how to apply validation using spring-boot approach and in a cleaner way.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1")
//@Validated
public class MyController {

@Autowired
private MyService service;

@PostMapping("/validate/{processor}/")
public MyResponse tokenizationSession(@Valid @RequestBody MyRequest myRequest, @PathVariable("processor") String processor) {
        return service.validate(myRequest, processor);
}
}

@Service
@Validated
class MyService {
    
    void validate(@Valid MyRequest input){
      // do something
    }
}

@Entity
class MyRequest {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String Address;
}
```

Comment: A side note: IMO it's better to not depend on `processor` parameter supplied by the user in the request url because of security risks. Instead, find the user type based on the user and pick the correct processor to apply.

Comment: Regarding the validation, i don't think you can dynamically map the validation attributes to the annotations eg: `@Size(min = "dynamic" , max = "dynamic")`. `Clean` way that i can think of is to have a ValidationConfig enum and use that on the ValidatorService . `enum ValidationConfig {
    DEFAULT(10, 20), MERCHANT(20, 20), RETAILER(30, 30);
    int firstNameLen;
    int lastNameLen;
    ValidationConfig(int firstNameLen,
                     int lastNameLen) {
        this.firstNameLen = firstNameLen;
        this.lastNameLen = lastNameLen;
    }
}`

Comment: I think the cleanest solution in this case would be implementing a custom validator for the `MyRequest` class. See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validator

Comment: Hi @Utku if I aaply custom validator than in that case how can I apply a mechanism which dynamically apply validation based upon path-variable. If would be great If you can give an idea how can I proceed with that . Thanks.

Comment: @gtiwari333 could you briefly explain why it is a security risk.

Comment: I do not know your business use case and can't tell 100% that its a security risk. But its a bad practice to rely on user data to validate data that could be possibly linked to business requirement. The idea is that a malicious user could change the `processor` parameter on the request and bypass the restrictions imposed for that user. Eg retailer user passing `processor` param for merchant and creating address more than 100 chars